# SwiftUI not update view using @Published

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, combine

I can't update the color of my Text base on the current status of my object.
The text should change color base on the variable status true or false.

I try below to simplify the code of where the data come from.

My contentview:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var gm = GameManager()

  @State var openSetting = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      openSetting.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Setting")
    }
  }
}
```

ContentView has a SettingView where I'm selecting setting and where I want to update my textColor based on the status of object

```swift
struct SettingView: View {
  @StateObject var gm : GameManager
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
      HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(gm.cockpit.ecamManager.door.doorarray) { doorName in
          Button {
            gm.close(door: doorName.doorName)
          } label: {
            Text(doorName.doorName)
            // Here where I want to change color
              .foregroundColor(doorName.isopen ? .orange : .green)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data come from GameManager which inside has a variable called cockpit:

```
class GameManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, ARSessionDelegate, ARSCNViewDelegate {

@Published var cockpit = MakeCockpit() // create the cockpit
  // do other stuff
}
```

MakeCockpit :

```
class MakeCockpit: SCNNode, ObservableObject {
  @Published var ecamManager = ECAMManager()

  // do other stuff
```

ECAMManager:

```
class ECAMManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var door = ECAMDoor()
  @Published var stanby = ECAMsby()    
}
```

And Finally... the Array I want to watch is in ECAMDoor class:

```
class ECAMDoor: ObservableObject {
  @Published var doorarray : [Door] = [] // MODEL
}
```

Now everything work fine as expected but the @Publish of the door array  not update my color in the setting view. I need to close the view and open again to se the color update.

Is someone can tell me where I mistake? I probably missed something .. hope I been clear (to many instance of class inside other class)

Comment: Nested `ObservableObject`s will not work as expected. You'd have to use `objectWillChange.send()` manually to pass the changes up the hierarchy. Is it possible to use `struct`s instead of `classes`? That will make everything *much* easier, as with value types, SwiftUI/Combine will do all of the work for you and everything will "just work"

Comment: Note, in `SettingView` you should use `@ObservedObject var gm : GameManager` not 
`@StateObject var gm : GameManager`, and not twice.